# Req.File.Path is undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js, multer

I am trying to use multer to upload an image to a mysql database , and I am getting an error stating

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

my App.js

```
var multer = require('multer');
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.post("/updateImage/add",multer({ dest: './public/uploads/'}).single('img') ,contentUpdate.addImage);
```

my contentUpdate.js

```
exports.addImage = function(req, res) {
   var path = (req.file.path).replace("public/", '');
    console.log(path);
   var data =
      {                
            image: path
      };

var URLs = data.PageURL;
connection.query('INSERT INTO `updatedimages` SET ?', [data], function(err, rows)
 {
    if (err)
    {
      console.log(err);
    } else
    {
      req.flash('success','Entry Successful');
      return res.redirect(URLs);
    }
 });
};
```

my updateImage.handlebars

```
<form  id="myForm" action='/updateImage/add'  method='POST'  >
    <div class="col-md-12" >
  <input name='img' type="file" class="form-control"  required/>
</div>
<div>

    <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-submit btn btn-primary ">

  </div>
```

Comment: check req.files (not file) contain any data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the proper encoding type in the HTML:

```
<form  id="myForm" action='/updateImage/add' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Even so, it's always good to *also* validate the input:

```
if (! req.file || ! req.file.path) {
  return res.sendStatus(400);
}
```

Comment: @ robertklep found that as soon as i uploaded the question ,but thank you!

Comment: @Tyron I believe you should mark this as the answer so that the rest of SO knows :P

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
<input name='img' type="file" class="form-control"  required/>
```

to

```
<input name='file' type="file" class="form-control"  required/>
```

And then try:

```
app.post("/updateImage/add",multer({ dest: './public/uploads/'}).single('file') ,contentUpdate.addImage);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I also noticed that my for was missing enctype="multipart/form-data" and that seemed to solve the problem. :D